# what is the meaning of pip: command in environment .yaml file?

Tags: python, windows, deep-learning, anaconda

I am setting up the environment for my project using a .yaml file. I am not very sure about the pip: command meaning in this file.

```
name: psp_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - ca-certificates=2020.4.5.1=hecc5488_0
  - certifi=2020.4.5.1=py36h9f0ad1d_0
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=
  - libffi=3.2.1=
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=
  - ncurses=6.2=
  - ninja=1.10.0=
  - openssl=1.1.1g=
  - pip=20.0.2=py36_3
  - python=3.6.7=
  - python_abi=3.6=1_cp36m
  - readline=7.0=
  - setuptools=46.4.0=py36_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=
  - tk=8.6.8=
  - wheel=0.34.2=py36_0
  - xz=5.2.5=
  - zlib=1.2.11=
  - pip:
    - scipy==1.4.1
    - matplotlib==3.2.1
    - tqdm==4.46.0
    - numpy==1.18.4
    - opencv-python==4.2.0.34
    - pillow==7.1.2
    - tensorboard==2.2.1
    - torch==1.6.0
    - torchvision==0.4.2
prefix: ~/anaconda3/envs/psp_env
```

what is the meaning of pip: command? Does it mean install the packages below? What is the difference bewteen the packages above and below pip?

Another question is I think some of these packages are linux/MAC specific (eg.readline). My system is windows. Is it ok for me just remove these packages away from the enviroment file?I have looked through other answers and think it is ok to remove them.

Comment: `pip` is a program to install modules for python. And packaged above can be system programs and libraries.

Comment: if you remove some programs then some functions may not work in Python. `readline` can be used in Python Shell to go back to previous command (and keep all commands on list as history) - so you may have to write the same commands again manually.

Comment: The problem is when I set up a anaconda environment. I will have ResolvePackageNotFound: error. I think this is because the build number will make the package specific to the operating sysytem (eg. py36h9f0ad1d_0). So i remove some build numbers. However some of libs/packages are not suitable for windows even if I remove the build number (eg. readline). Do I understand correctly?

Comment: For pip problem, what I dont understand is why some packages are above pip command and some are below it.... Are they all installed?

Comment: some python modules have the same names as system programs/libraries. For example:  to run python module `sqlite` it has to install system program/library `sqlite`. To run python module `tkinter` it has to instal system program/library `tk` (or rather language `tcl` and its GUI library `tk`)

Comment: If this is a yaml file to configure a conda environment, I would guess that above the pip, those packages get conda installed, while below the pip, they are pip installed.

Comment: @BigBO About packages like `readline`, I would not assume they're specific to a platform. You might get a platform-specific version of some of them, but hopefully conda will resolve that for you. They look like Python packages to me, needed on any platform, but I could be wrong. In any case, it's an easy test: does the code still run when you remove them? If so, it was probably OK to remove them. But I'm not sure why you want to bother removing them in the first place: are they causing problems?

Comment: @joanis I'm nice - OP asked exacly `"what is the meaning of pip: command?"` And I nicely explained this. And I also explained that command above `pip` are normal modules, not pip modules. I don't understand why you think it wasn't nice. It was normal answer - I assumed that OP may not know what is `pip` and OP needs this explanation.

Comment: @joanis yes, there is no need to continue it. We may have different experience with beginner's question so we can see problem in question in different way. I tried to be nice in first comment - but maybe I wrote it too briefly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this specific YAML configuration file format, but I've seen similar ones before, and the semantics for the dependencies was:

- by default (i.e., above the `pip:` block), dependencies are installed by the package manager (conda in your case) -- that's equivalent to running `conda install <package>` for each of them
- the `pip:` block is to declare things that are not to be installed by the package manager, and should be installed using pip instead -- that's equivalent to running `poip install <package>` for each of them.

There may be a number of reasons to put a package in the pip section, most commonly:

- it's not available as a conda package, only on as a pip package,
- the version on conda is not the right one, pip is required to get the right version.